# How does the second hydrolysis of phthalimide work (hydrolysis of amide)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrolysis, amides

In the hydrolysis of Phthalimides we can see two successive hydrolysis of "amides" [see ChemLibre for a nice mechanism](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Supplemental_Modules_(Organic_Chemistry)/Amines/Synthesis_of_Amines/Gabriel_Synthesis)

This is interesting because normally (also according to [ChemLibre](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/21%3A_Carboxylic_Acid_Derivatives-_Nucleophilic_Acyl_Substitution_Reactions/21.02%3A_Nucleophilic_Acyl_Substitution_Reactions)) amides are very stable (the amine is a poor leaving group) and don't react.

Nevertheless the first hydrolysis can be rationalized because the nitrogen electrons are delocalized and there is ring strain. Similar to how beta-lactams are more reactive than normal amides.

However, the second reaction appears to be just a normal amide hydrolysis. How does this happen?

Comment: Generally under forcing conditions. Elevated temperature, concentrated reagents and long reaction times.

Comment: It *is* normal amide hydrolysis, so I don't get why you're asking.

Comment: @Mithoron I was under the impression that amide hydrolysis wasn’t possible based on the ChemLibre website. However, I guess it can be forced.